# Python unittests do not immediately run

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, fastapi, python-unittest

I have a test suite in a file called: `my_tests.py` which looks similar to below:

```
class TestSomeClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        ...
        ...
        cls.client = TestClient(app, headers=cls.headers) 

    def setUp(self):
        ...
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        ...
        ...

    def test_sanity(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
        self.assertNotEqual("HELLO", "hello")

    # more tests omitted
```

I run the test suite using the CLI like so: `python -m unittest tests.my_tests.TestSomeClass`. It hangs for about 30-35s, and then seemingly actually starts running the tests (printing my print statements in the actual tests), and then finally displays the report:

```
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 1.986s

OK
```

Any ideas on what's happening in those 30-35s? Thanks!

I tried things like adding an `__init__.py`, fiddling with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

if it is needed, and tried the `--verbose` flag to see if there is some overhead process im missing. Kinda new to this so not sure what im missing here.

===

Heeding on the advice of minimally reproducing:

```
python -m unittest tests.my_tests.TestSomeClass.test_sanity
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.705s

OK
```

The `TestSomeClass` has no overriden methods (no setupclass, setup, or teardown). Same hang up.

EDIT: I have figured out that the reason it is slow, is because of the imports at the top of the file.

Comment: Did you try to check what happens in the `setUpClass` code? (For example, are you expecting it to make a network connection, or load extremely heavyweight libraries such as Pytorch)? Also: *why is this tagged `fastapi`*?

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `setUpClass` just sets some class vars and loads a config file. However, I commented it out and ran `test_sanity` and it still hung up.

Comment: "I have figured out that the reason it is slow, is because of the imports at the top of the file.": which import is that then specifically?

Comment: Is this a case where one of the imports is a module that could benefit from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/419185#419185